# SQL - Group values by range

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, grouping

I have following query:

```
SELECT
polutionmm2 AS metric,
sum(cnt) as value
FROM polutiondistributionstatistic as p inner join crates as c on p.crateid = c.id
WHERE
c.name = '154' 
and to_timestamp(startts) >= '2021/01/20 00:00:00' group by polutionmm2
```

this query returns these values:

```
"metric","value"
50,580
100,8262
150,1548
200,6358
250,869
300,3780
350,505
400,2248
450,318
500,1674
550,312
600,7420
650,1304
700,2445
750,486
800,985
850,139
900,661
950,99
1000,550
```

I would need to edit the query in a way that it groups them toghether in ranges of 100, starting from 0. So everything that has a metric value between 0 and 99 should be one row, and the value the sum of the rows... like this:

```
"metric","value"
0,580
100,9810
200,7227
300,4285
400,2556
500,1986
600,8724
700,2931
800,1124
900,760
1000,550
```

The query will run over about 500.000 rows.. Can this be done via query? Is it efficient?

EDIT:

there can be up to 500 ranges, so an automatic way of grouping them would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `generate_series()` and a [range type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html) to generate the the ranges you want, e.g.:

```
select int4range(x.start, case when x.start = 1000 then null else x.start + 100 end, '[)') as range
from generate_series(0,1000,100) as x(start)
```

This generates the ranges `[0,100)`, `[100,200)` and so on up until `[1000,)`.

You can adjust the width and the number of ranges by using different parameters for generate_series() and adjusting the expression that evaluates the last range

This can be used in an outer join to aggregate the values per range:

```
with ranges as (
  select int4range(x.start, case when x.start = 1000 then null else x.start + 100 end, '[)') as range
  from generate_series(0,1000,100) as x(start)
)  
select r.range as metric,
       sum(t.value)
from ranges r
  left join the_table t on r.range @> t.metric
group by range;
```

The expression `r.range @> t.metric` tests if the metric value falls into the (generated) range

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=62199eb9aa25f20382e337fd7641d666)

Comment: I totally forget `generate_series()` , great answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a Pseudo table with interval you like and join with that table.
I'll use recursive CTE for this case.

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS(
   select 0 St, 99 Ed
    UNION ALL
    select St + 100, Ed + 100 from cte where St <= 1000 
)   
select cte.st as metric,sum(tb.value) as value from cte 
inner join [tableName] tb --with OP query result
on tb.metric between cte.St and cte.Ed
group by cte.st
order by st
```

here is [DB<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=26469d247aa5c3a70b256524205d883d) with some pseudo data.

Answer (score 1):

use conditional aggregation

```
SELECT
case when polutionmm2>=0 and polutionmm2<100 then '100' 
when polutionmm2>=100 and polutionmm2<200 then '200' 
........
when polutionmm2>=900 and polutionmm2<1000 then '1000'
end  AS metric,
sum(cnt) as value
FROM polutiondistributionstatistic as p inner join crates as c on p.crateid = c.id
WHERE
c.name = '154' 
and to_timestamp(startts) >= '2021/01/20 00:00:00' 
group by case when polutionmm2>=0 and polutionmm2<100 then '100' 
when polutionmm2>=100 and polutionmm2<200 then '200' 
........
when polutionmm2>=900 and polutionmm2<1000 then '1000'
end
```

Comment: thank you.. is there an automatic way too? there can be up to 500 ranges, that would make the query quite long and a lot to write manually..

Comment: maybe divide the value by 100 and then round, and group by this new value?

Comment: @sharkyenergy yap you that can be another way